# loop 2 taking input automatically

Tags: c, loops, do-while

My code is behaving weirdly. In loop 1 it is working perfectly but in loop 2 it is automatically printing ASCII value 10. please help!.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    int loop =1;

    do{

        printf("\nLoop = %d\nWrite character of which you want to find acii values: ", loop);
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("\nASCII value of %c is %d.", c, c);
        loop++;

    }while(c != 'Z');

    printf("\n******END*****");
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

10 is ASCII for newline.  You are reading whitespace, which you can avoid by using

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Note the additional blank before the character specifier. It instructs scanf to ignore white space.